# Add to ArrayList from different WebForms

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I have 2 web forms in webform1 I have 2 buttons (Add and Show_WebForm2) and a textbox. In WebForm1, when the user types in the names in the textbox and clicks add button the name is added to the ArrayList. When the user is done typing in the names in WebForm1 they open WebForms2. In WebForms2 there is also a textbox and an add button. When the user types in the names in this TextBox I want it to be added to the same ArrayList variable which I used in WebForm1. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
    public ArrayList FullNameApplicantArray = new ArrayList();
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FullNameApplicantArray.Add("(" + TextBox1.Text +")");
        Session["ListOfApplicants"] = FullNameApplicantArray[0];

        foreach (var item in Session["ListOfApplicants"].ToString())
        {
            Debug.Write(item);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx");

    }
```

[image]

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FullNameApplicantArray.Add("(" + TextBox1.Text + ")");
        Session["ListOfApplicants"] = FullNameApplicantArray[0];

        foreach (var item in Session["ListOfApplicants"].ToString())
        {
            Debug.Write(item);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of issues in that code. When the user clicks Add, first thing is retrieving the list from session, not storing into session. After adding an item to the list, we need to update session.

**WebForm1**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList FullNameApplicantArray = (ArrayList)Session["FullNameApplicantArray"] ?? new ArrayList();
    FullNameApplicantArray.Add("(" + TextBox1.Text + ")");

    foreach (var item in FullNameApplicantArray)
    {
        Debug.Write(item);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    Session["FullNameApplicantArray"] = FullNameApplicantArray;
}


protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx");
}
```

**WebForm2**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList FullNameApplicantArray = (ArrayList)Session["FullNameApplicantArray"] ?? new ArrayList();
    FullNameApplicantArray.Add("(" + TextBox1.Text + ")");

    foreach (var item in FullNameApplicantArray)
    {
        Debug.Write(item);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    Session["FullNameApplicantArray"] = FullNameApplicantArray;
}
```

Also take into account that the output window for Debug.Write(item) depends on how VS is configured.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution in your code, just use session across different WebForms.

In the second WebForm page, in click event, just assign the session to the array,
add to the array, then save to the session.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList FullNameApplicantArray2 = new ArrayList();
    FullNameApplicantArray2 = Session["ListOfApplicants"];
    FullNameApplicantArray2.Add("(" + TextBox1.Text + ")");
    Session["ListOfApplicants"] = FullNameApplicantArray2;

    foreach (var item in Session["ListOfApplicants"].ToString())
    {
        Debug.Write(item);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```

Also in your Button1_click, you need to save the entire list instead of only the first element:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FullNameApplicantArray.Add("(" + TextBox1.Text +")");
    Session["ListOfApplicants"] = FullNameApplicantArray;

    foreach (var item in Session["ListOfApplicants"].ToString())
    {
        Debug.Write(item);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a second instance of the ArrayList on the second form and assign it to what is saved in session.

```
public ArrayList FullNameApplicantArray = (ArrayList)Session["ListOfApplicants"];

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FullNameApplicantArray.Add("(" + TextBox1.Text + ")");
    Session["ListOfApplicants"] = FullNameApplicantArray;

    foreach (var item in Session["ListOfApplicants"].ToString())
    {
        Debug.Write(item);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```